GameObject not being created when giving transform a parent Unity
I am making chess in unity2D and am trying to set the pieces as children of the squares as shown in the function below, however it is not creating new game objects with no errors being output.
private void DrawPiece(int piece, Transform parentSquare)
{
    if (!pieceSprites.ContainsKey(piece))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Piece sprite not found for piece code: {piece}");
        return;
    }

    string pieceBinary = Convert.ToString(piece, 2).PadLeft(5, '0');

    GameObject pieceObj = new GameObject($"Piece_{pieceBinary}@{parentSquare.position.x * 8 + parentSquare.position.y}");
    pieceObj.transform.position = parentSquare.position;

    pieceObj.transform.parent = parentSquare;

    SpriteRenderer sr = pieceObj.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    sr.sortingOrder = 1;
    sr.sprite = pieceSprites[piece];
    pieceObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(pieceSize, pieceSize, 1);
}

void DrawAllPieces()
{
    // Clear old pieces
    foreach (Transform child in transform)
    {
        if (child.name.StartsWith("Piece_"))
            Destroy(child.gameObject);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        int piece = Board.Square[i];
        if (piece != Piece.None)
        {
            int x = i % 8;
            int y = i / 8;
            Vector2 position = new Vector2(x - 3.5f, y - 3.5f);

            // Find the square corresponding to the piece's position
            GameObject square = FindSquare(position);
            if (square == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError($"Square not found at position: {position}");
                continue;
            }

            DrawPiece(piece, square.transform);

        }
    }
}

private GameObject FindSquare(Vector2 position) {     
string squareName = $"Square_{position.x + 3.5f}_{position.y + 3.5f}";     return GameObject.Find(squareName); 
}

I tried setting the pieceObj parent to transform and it generates the piece fine.
Output with pieceObj.transform.parent = parentSquare;

Output with pieceObj.transform.parent = transform;

Any help would be much appreciated :)

What is parentSquare? How do you get it?

I find parentSquare through private GameObject FindSquare(Vector2 position) {     string squareName = $"Square_{position.x + 3.5f}_{position.y + 3.5f}";     return GameObject.Find(squareName); }
however parentSquare is always set to the correct GameObject

Are you sure parentSquare is found by this function?

Yes i've edited the question with all the code for finding the square and where the draw piece is called

I didn't see any obvious mistake. Is there only one object called Square_0_0 in the scene? Are there any script attached on square objects that can automatically destroy child objects? I suggest you can attach a debug script to each pieceObj. In this script, OnEnable and OnDisable functions are required to print logs and determine the lifecycle of the piece object.

There are 64 squares each with a unique name and no script that can destroy the pieces. Ill have a look at the debug for the piece

It is probably just returning null so your pieces are all created at scene root level .... have in mind that float is not precise and can result in strings like e.g. Square_6.00000001_1.999999999 ... you should probably do some Mathf.RoundToInt there first

This was an issue with float not being precise as @derHugo mentioned I just needed to use Mathf.RoundToInt
